# Row Notification from background (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

When I am in background , can I recieve a Row Notification?

Comment: I have a complete step-by-step guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084955/windows-phone-8-notifications-and-background-tasks/42694667#42694667

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, it can't!

On [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), we can read the following:

> You can use a raw notification to send information to your
>   application. If your application is not currently running, the raw
>   notification is discarded on the Microsoft Push Notification Service
>   and is not delivered to the device.

And by the Windows Phone app lifecycle definition, a background app is not currently running!

Also, found the following post in App Hub about someone with the same question:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/96549/576520.aspx