# Push Notification Background Task Crashes Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator/Device

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Has anyone else had problems running the push notification background task sample (Javascript) on the WP 8.1 emulator? Sample link is [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d/file/50987/41/Raw%20notifications%20sample.zip).

When I run the sample app, register the background task, then send a raw notification via the [notification simulator](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/04/windows-phone-8-1-trying-out-push-notifications.aspx), the entire emulator crashes. See images below:

[image]
[image]

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, or knows how to fix it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it seems that an official sample application should work out of the box...

Just as a side note, I've tested this in my actual application with the same results; using both the notification simulator, and sending real raw notifications from my app server.

Comment: I have a complete step-by-step guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084955/windows-phone-8-notifications-and-background-tasks/42694667#42694667

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion below MS will try address the fix for the issue to the next major release:
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/winphone/wpnotifications.aspx?ID=34232b54-e52a-40df-af54-c8d0d8f661b2

> Victor Senkevich on Tue, 09 Dec 2014 16:58:17
>
> Got the answer from MS Support:
>
> "Hi Victor,
>
> I received word back from our product group regarding this issue. 
>   Unfortunately we won’t be able to fix this in Windows Phone 8.1 but we
>   will try to address the problem in the next major OS version." ....
>
> I have already redeveloped this bg task in C#